# PHP - Redirect only once

Tags: php, redirect

How can I make the `header("Location: /path");` to only redirect once?

Currenlty I have this:

```
//If account is locked by user.
if($userdata['account_locked']  == 1):
    header("Location: /account/locked");
endif;
```

This script is checked in my header file. But it doesn't work, since it will just create a loop-redirect (infinit loop)

How can I do, so it only redirect once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this snippet appear on the page you are about to go? is this a global check?

Comment: Maybe this will help:

 http://serverfault.com/questions/229435/how-to-break-from-infinite-loop-caused-by-php-script-running-as-root

Comment: What is the purpose of the `/account/locked`-page? If it is some kind of "I agree"-page, you should set the `$userdata['account_locked']` to something else then `1`.

Comment: @Joseph: It's a global check, he says it's in his header file which I assume is included in every page.

Comment: so if this is so, then even the "account locked" page also has this? then it's redirecting to it's self! remove this code from that page to prevent it.

Comment: It is a global check. The header.php is included in every file.
The purpose of the account/locked page is that the user can "lock" their account. (Example if they leave their computer or something)

Comment: @oliverbj then remove it from the "account locked" page. what's the point putting a redirection there when it redirects to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple, but it's a bit ugly...

```
//If account is locked by user.
if($userdata['account_locked']  == 1):
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "/account/locked") header("Location: /account/locked");
endif;
```

You should use MVC, a controller should be aware of the loop.

EDITED
It's better to use

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

instead of

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].
```

Edit: Changed from URL to URI.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. Just a note, it is not $_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'] but $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Note the I instead of L, at the end of UR. :-) But thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($userdata['account_locked']  == 1 && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/account/locked'):
    header("Location: /account/locked");
endif;
```